# How do I remove this Site Content browser item from Quick Launch side bar?

Tags: 2013

Here is the item I would like to remove:

[image: site content item]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the tree view is enabled on your site, you can hide it by setting settings,

1. Go to **Site Settings**
2. Click on **Navigation Elements**
3. Deselect **Enable Tree View** check box

That's it.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to be just the setting I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer : edit your masterpage :)

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" runat="server">
                <%--<div class="ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox">
                    <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                        runat="server"
                        id="idNavLinkViewAll"
                        PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                        NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"
                        Text="<%$Resources:wss,AllSiteContentMore%>"
                        accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"
                        CssClass="ms-core-listMenu-item ms-core-listMenu-heading" />
                </div>--%>
```

Courtesy from : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5d30118a-8be7-4ed7-9f0d-b40ecf1054fd/a-menu-item-called-site-contents-on-the-left-site-menu-of-my-site?forum=sharepointgeneral